# Get value out of a tolist([ data object in Terraform

Tags: variables, terraform, tolist

I have this terraform output:

```
output "cloud_connection" {
    value =  data.cloud_connection.current.connection[0]
  }
```

```
$ terraform output
cloud_connection = tolist([
  {

    "id" = "123"
    "settings" = toset([
      {
        "vlan_id" = 100
      },
    ])
    "connection_type" = "cloud"
  },
])
```

I need to get the vlan_id to reuse it later on.

```
output "cloud_connection" {
    value =  data.cloud_connection.current.connection[0].settings[0].vlan_id
  }
```

```
$ terraform output
cloud_connection = tolist([
    tolist([
      100,
    ]),
  ])
```

The problem is I can't seem to be able to get the vlan id out of a list.

When I try:

```
output "cloud_connection" {
    value =  data.connection.current.connection[0].settings[0].vlan_id[0]
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```
│ Elements of a set are identified only by their value and don't have any separate index or key to select
│ with, so it's only possible to perform operations across all elements of the set.
```

How can I get the vlan_id alone?

Thanks

Comment: What is `data.cloud_connection.current`?

Comment: cloud_connection is my my terraform custom data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know that you have at least 1 element in each of the nested collections, the idiomatic way would be to use [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) with some flattening:

```
output "cloud_connection" {
  value = flatten(data.connection.current.connection[*].settings[*].vlan_id)[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `join`, assuming you´re getting the following output:

```
$ terraform output
cloud_connection = tolist([
    tolist([
      100,
    ]),
  ])
```

For example:

```
output "cloud_connection" {
    value =  join(",",data.cloud_connection.current.connection[0].settings[0].vlan_id)
  }
```

That returns:

```
cloud_connection = "100"
```